# How to correctly judge the performance in Java using a profiler?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, profiler

I hava a Java project in which I am using threading, but performance of my project is not good and its running very slow on different machines.I want to improve the performance. I used VisualVM profiler to find where it consumes time, but I am not able to find it out. How to resolve this issue?Is it because of threading? And also tell me which profiler should I Use? 
Please Suggest!!...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating a large number of short lived threads? How many threads are created in the lifetime of your application? How many do you have at one time? (I'm not looking for specific numbers, just approximate figures)

Comment: Well... If you are using many threads, then there will be syncronization issues... Performance will be hit because of threads blocking one another.. As a thumb rule always remember- "Never create one extra thread than whats necessary..." And more the numbe rof threads doesnt always mean higher throughput.. it might mean better response times...

Comment: And to add to that; the maximum number of threads that can be comfortably run simultaneously is `2*NumberOfCPUCores`. Any more won't give you a performance boost and may slow things down. So if you have a dual core you should avoid having more than 4 threads at any one time

Comment: Your question is too vague. You need to say what you have tried, what the symptoms are, what your code is doing, what you did find out with the profiler, etc.

Comment: I am doing DataBase operations inside the threads over the 50 files. actually I wanted to identify why it is going slow by the profiler

Answer (score 1):

CPU profile your application which should give you the hotspots. CPU profiling for VisualVM is explained [here](https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html). It will also assist you to find out if it is because of threads or there is something else in the application which is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to track the following:

1. Free Heap
2. Thread count
3. Timeout connection from pool
4. All application threads and their states
5. GC activities
6. Rolled Back transaction
7. Messages on the queue

all these things directly effects any application performance. so you can track the above by using `visualvm` from JDK, or `Java Mission Control`. Mission Control is bundled with JDK starting at JDK 7 Update 40. With these tools you can connect to any JVM process, local or remote. If you're connecting to a remote JVM, you should have enabled JMX via JVM parameter `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010`

Comment: But How can I achieve ?

Comment: @Siddharth if i got your question right then, as i mentioned above, there is many profiling and monitoring tools for java applications, and the `visualvm` and `Java Mission Control` are two of them, it can give you the `CPU Profiling, Memory status, total loaded classes, Threads and its all related info, and more`.

Comment: yes I understand what you said. I am already using VisualVM but i m not able to find out due to which method my project is going slow please suggest me.

Comment: In the visualvm>>Threads Tab you will see a button in the above right corner Thread Dump, this button generates a file called thread dump, this file contains your whole threads, generate a multiple thread dumps and trace you application threads, you will clearly see what the slow thread is currently doing, where exactly the method caused the slowness.

Comment: don't forget to select as answer if that helped u, thanks.